# regular expression search in objective c

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I'm trying to remove everything from a string that is NOT an html tag or comment tag.

I have this code which works quite well for most strings:

```
  NSString* HTMLPlainText = [HTML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<(.*?)>" withString:@" " options: NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange (0, [HTML length])];
```

But it does not work for strings that contain new lines. For example this string will not be altered: "< tag name \n more tag > words I want"

The new line throws it off. I can run a whole other search to remove all /n tags before running this one and that works, but it seems like there must be a better way....

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the `NSRegularExpressionSearch` flag and using simple `NSString` methods, create an actual `NSRegularExpression` object, and use it's methods to do the replacement.

That will give you much more flexibility, including configuration options for newlines.